# No instances in app engine admin console

Tags: google-app-engine, instance, google-compute-engine

I just deployed an app on Google App Engine and everything went fine. The app runs smoothly at < project-id >.appspot.com. I deployed it a few more times and one time there was an error:

```
05:56 PM Unknown error TEMPORARY_ERROR: . Deployed Version: 5.379937995233868117
ERROR: Unknown error TEMPORARY_ERROR: . Deployed Version: 5.379937995233868117
05:56 PM Rolling back the update.  This can sometimes take a while since a VM version is being rolled back.
Could not start serving the given version.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
```

The app was still running and I could manage it to successfully deploy it again. But since then when I go to the admin console there is not a single instance listed. Only a small grey icon is shown with a flash. The path to the icon is '//ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/activityindicator/offline.png' (I looked it up in the CSS).

The app runs on a managed VM with a custom runtime.

[image: No instances listed]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: sure you are looking at the logs/instances for ALL versions and not for a previous (no longer default) version ?

Comment: there is only one version.

Comment: Ha, I didn't play with managed vms yet, but I think your instances will show up as compute engine instances and no longer as GAE instances.

Comment: That is correct, but they appeared as App Engine instances as well before the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

I was planning to deploy a managed VM with custom runtime and was watching this Google I/O bytes [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8jZHc0NS6A) and it seems it's expected. The manged vms with custom runtimes will show under Compute Engine on your developer console (4:35 in this video). You will be able to manage your App through App Engine on developer console.